# Qt: Dynamic QMainWindow sizing

Tags: qt, qt4, qmainwindow

I have a Qt 4.8.5 application. The top level widget is derived from QMainWindow. The central widget (QMainWindow::setCentralWidget) is derived from QTableView. The data model for the view is derived from QAbstractTableModel.

The data model changes dynamically during the life of the application, without human intervention. The application GUI is viewed on a wall screen in a control room for multiple people to see, and typically nobody directly interacts with the GUI.

The changes to the data model are significant including dynamic table rows and columns. The application window needs to size to fit the QTableView every time QTableView::setModel is called to install a new data model, such that a minimal footprint is maintained. Out of the box behavior is for the window to take on an initial size that will not change when a new data model is introduced. My various attempts to program a window that grows and shrinks dynamically have all failed.

Additional information ...
This is not a new application, but one that has been in use for a number of years. The technique that made it work was indeed the computation of size and setting fixed size widgets. I decided to revisit this app due to some scenarios where the size estimate was wrong. These scenarios are not the main use case of the application, but cases where individual users ran the app on their local workstations, not the control room wall.

I decided to focus on why different use cases produced different results, learning several interesting things. The sizing calculation accuracy was impacted by from where the app was executed. Directly logged into a Linux workstation always worked. Failures had to do with remote login: windows->putty/exceed, Linux 'ssh'; all dependent on remote host architectures.

It turns out the GUI style used by Qt impacts the fidelity of my size estimate. Since the app did not explicitly set style, the style used varied in the scenarios mentioned above. The size estimate inaccuracy was solved by choosing an explicit style in the application code.

Comment: Have you tried to use QWidget::setGeometry() ? I recommend creating a little example app tor testing and sharing the code example. I mean setGeometry() is also an available method for QMainWindow.

Comment: My understanding of QWidget::setGeometry() is that it is for explicitly forcing widget sizes to pixel values. I want to leave that level of sizing to layout management. I rather manage QsizePolicy and related objects.

Comment: Maybe I haven't understood well, dont you wanted the QMainwindow to adjust its size regarding the QTableView size? If it is the case, I dont think the framwork works so. I'd personally try to have a slot grabbing the tablewiew size once model changed, estimate an appropriate geometry for the mainwindow, use setgeometry, and let size policies apply. But I just have an average experience on qt, maybe you'll get better advice.

Comment: You can't have a window in a layout, so a layout can't change size of a window... Perhaps you want to ask the table view its size hints, and resize the window based on that? Or, perhaps this method gives you the size you want: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractscrollarea.html#maximumViewportSize

Comment: The difficulty with spacm's suggestion is the "estimate an appropriate geometry" of a complex widget.

Comment: I have previously tried in my QMainWidget code, immediately following QTableView::setModel, `QApplication::processEvents(QEventLoop::ExcludeUserInputEvents); resize(sizeHint());` This did not help.

Comment: I think you should search a compromise between your user experience constraints, and the means you have of adjusting your view geometry, beginning with simple methods. I have a limited idea of your use cases,  but I imagine that if the screen doesn't belong only to your app, it would be convenient to use pre-defined fixed geometries of the window: one for less than 5x5 table, one for les than 10x10, one for 15X15, as an example. Or define a pagination of the model, with alternating views. This simplifies the estimation process.

Comment: See the Additional information I edited into my original post.

Comment: Ok, have you solved your problem then? Or still searching a better solution?

Comment: Problem solved, although computing sizes is not as elegant as I would like.